# dayRender not properly working in fullcalendar on given dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar for day event booking.I want to make some day color change based on given dates.But it render the color in the whole calendar.It makes all the cell green.
Here is the code,

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
    var disabledDates = ["2017-08-17","2017-08-23"];
    if ($.inArray(date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),disabledDates)) {
        //alert("success");
        cell.css("background-color", "green");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `$.inArray` correctly. It does not return `true` or `false`, which you would use to resolve an `if` statement. Instead it returns an integer representing the index at which it first finds a matching value. If it doesn't find a match, it returns -1.

Your problem is occurring because JavaScript treats `0` as loosely equal to `false` (i.e. `0 == false`, but `0 !== false`), and all other numbers loosely as equal to `true`. Therefore if `$.inArray` returns anything other than `0` (i.e. 0 is returned where matched the value in the first array index), your `if` statement will treat is as if it had returned `true`, and consequently change the background colour. That's why it changes it for all of them except 2017-08-17.

This version will work correctly, testing that the index return is > -1 (an integer, not a bool) before setting the background colour:

```
dayRender: function(date, cell) {
  var disabledDates = ["2017-08-17", "2017-08-23"];
  if ($.inArray(date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"), disabledDates) > -1) {
    console.log(date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
    cell.css("background-color", "green");
  }
}
```

See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/ for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: No problem, happy to help. It always pays to read the documentation! :-)